# Why is this not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called `offer.js` which does this (it outputs data fine);

```
function rsOffersAll() {
    global.MSSQL_MYDB.connect().then(function(error, result) {
        global.MSSQL_MYDB.request(global.MSSQL_MYDB).query('SELECT Top(10) * FROM [Broadcast].[Offer]').then(function (result) {
            console.dir(result);
            return result;
        });
    });
}

module.exports.rsOffersAll = rsOffersAll();
```

In my router file, I have this:

```
const Offer = require('../models/offer');
Offer.rsOffersAll();
```

If I run the above I get this error:

```
Offer.rsOffersAll();
      ^

TypeError: Offer.rsOffersAll is not a function
```

Why is it not a function? And how do I execute that function so that I can get the data into another file?

Comment: I think this should be: `module.exports.rsOffersAll = rsOffersAll;`

Comment: because you are calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsOffersAll()` evaluates to the return value you get when you call the `rsOffersAll` function.

That function has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

`undefined` is not a function.

If you want to export the function, then **don't call it** on the line you are trying to export from.

```
module.exports.rsOffersAll = rsOffersAll;
```

Comment: Got it. So in my code `module.exports.rsOffersAll` became the data from the database because I assigned it to `rsOfferAll()` which ran the function and returned the data. So when I called `Offer.rsOffersAll()` in my other file it was no longer a function but just a set of data.